# Texture.channel does not work, throws back shader error when trying to define a UV1 for lightMap and aoMAP

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

When I declare a texture for aoMap and then pass it into a new material, it won't use the second UV. This is my code:

```
const lightMap = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, 'lightmap.png')
const brickMap = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, 'albedo.jpg')
brickMap.wrapS = brickMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
lightMap.flipY = false;

const aomaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      map: brickMap,
      lightMap: lightMap,
      aoMap: lightMap,
      lightMapIntensity: 1
});
```

This is the result. As you can see, the lightmap is using the 0,0 tile in this large plane. When it should be using the second UV coords.
[Floor plane of my scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niDXs.jpg)

And if I add the line:

```
lightMap.channel = 1;
```

Then I get this error:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: Shader Error 0 - VALIDATE_STATUS false

Program Info Log: Vertex shader is not compiled.

VERTEX

ERROR: 0:384: 'uv1' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:384: 'constructor' : not enough data provided for construction
ERROR: 0:387: 'uv1' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:387: 'constructor' : not enough data provided for construction

  379: #endif
  380: #ifdef USE_ALPHAMAP
  381:  vAlphaMapUv = ( alphaMapTransform * vec3( ALPHAMAP_UV, 1 ) ).xy;
  382: #endif
  383: #ifdef USE_LIGHTMAP
> 384:  vLightMapUv = ( lightMapTransform * vec3( LIGHTMAP_UV, 1 ) ).xy;
  385: #endif
  386: #ifdef USE_AOMAP
  387:  vAoMapUv = ( aoMapTransform * vec3( AOMAP_UV, 1 ) ).xy;
  388: #endif
  389: #ifdef USE_BUMPMAP
  390:  vBumpMapUv = ( bumpMapTransform * vec3( BUMPMAP_UV, 1 ) ).xy;
```

I have also uploaded the GLB to gltf report, and I can see it has two UVs: TEXCOORD_0:f32 and TEXCOORD_1:f32.
I have also re-imported the model into Blender and I see the second UV.
I have been researching for hours, with very little success. I know three.js supports up to four UV sets, so I should be able to use the second UV.
In the docs it even says that lightMap and aoMap require a second UV.

Thanks in advance.